# How to change the icon displayed in the task switcher?

Tags: windows, rust, tauri

I'm not quite sure where the icon is coming from that's displayed in Task Switcher (alt-tab) on Windows.
The icon is provided in tauri.conf.json as:

- tauri/bundle/icon
- tauri/systemTray/iconPath

The correct icon is displayed in the window title bar and also on the Windows task bar, but some default icon is displayed in the task switcher when cycling through the tasks with alt-tab.
However, when I start the debug build exe "manually" (not through vite), there is an additional cmd window opened for the debug output, and that window has the correct icon in task switcher.

What am I doing wrong? How is it supposed to work? Has anyone seen a Tauri app with custom icon displayed in the Task Switcher? Spent quite some time with setting up resources, trying to change the icon in the Rust backend, checked other app sources to no avail.